# field_group: the save button is now in the wrong place

Tags: 7, entities

I am using the Field Group module to group my content input fields in my add and edit node pages.  After adding a few groups, I noticed that the Save / Preview buttons moved from the bottom of the page, to a position between my un-grouped content and the groups that I have just created.  How do I move the buttons back to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the weight of the Save / preview buttons, and place them at the bottom with form alter.

Weight is used to sort the list of form elements before being output; lower numbers appear before higher numbers.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Only change actions container (submit, preview, cancel buttons) weight
  // on node edit forms.
  if (!empty($form['#node_edit_form']) && $form['#node_edit_form'] == TRUE) {
    $form['actions']['#weight'] = 100; 
  }
}
```